# How can I get desired JSON structure after encoding in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I have a struct name OpaqueData. I want to convert that object to JSON as in the following structure.

```
{
    "dataDescriptor": "Some Text",
    "dataValue": "Some Text"
                }
```

Strcut model of OpaqueData is as follows.

```
struct OpaqueData: Codable {

            let dataDescriptor: String

            let dataValue: String

        }
```

after encoding to json object dataValue property comes first and data descriptor comes second. How can I get desired JSON Structure after encoding strcut model to json.

```
let opaqueData = OpaqueData(dataDescriptor:"some text",dataValue: "some text")
let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(opaqueData)
let jsonString = String(data: encodedData!, encoding: .utf8)

print(jsonString!)
```

printed json string looks like this.

```
{
    "dataValue": "some text"

    "dataDescriptor": "some text",

                }
```

Comment: The printed JSON string does not look like that. Please post the actual output.

Comment: struct OpaqueData: Codable {
    
    let dataDescriptor: String
    
    let dataValue: String
    
}

let opaqueData = OpaqueData(dataDescriptor:"some text",dataValue: "some text")
print(opaqueData)

let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(opaqueData)
let jsonString = String(data: encodedData!, encoding: .utf8)
print(jsonString!)         output: OpaqueData(dataDescriptor: "some text", dataValue: "some text")
{"dataValue":"some text","dataDescriptor":"some text"}

Comment: @Leo Dabus when I am trying to make a payment transaction request requested  json body mismatches at OpaqueData.

Comment: I am getting the success response when I have actual transaction request like {
    "dataDescriptor": "Some Text",
    "dataValue": "Some Text"
                } while testing on REST Client

Comment: {  "createTransactionRequest": {  "merchantAuthentication": {  "name": "YOUR_API_LOGIN_ID",   "transactionKey": "YOUR_TRANSACTION_KEY"  }, "refId": "123456", "transactionRequest": {
            "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction", "amount": "5", "payment": { "opaqueData": {"dataDescriptor": "COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT",   "dataValue": "PAYMENT_NONCE_GOES_HERE"   }}  } }} I have a json request body like this when used  sortedKey that OpaqueData is fine. but another node differ in structure how can I used sortedKey for nested json output formatting

Comment: Please stop posting code and text into comments. Please [edit] your question with all relevant details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to output your json dictionary string ordered you need to set the encoder `outputFormatting` property to `.sortedKeys`:

```
struct OpaqueData: Codable {
    let dataDescriptor: String
    let dataValue: String
}

let opaqueData = OpaqueData(dataDescriptor:"some text", dataValue: "some text")

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .sortedKeys
let encodedData = try! encoder.encode(opaqueData)

let jsonString = String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8)!

print(jsonString)  // "{"dataDescriptor":"some text","dataValue":"some text"}\n"
```

Comment: How can we use it , if we have three properties?

Comment: The API you are using looks very sensible. Why would it require a certain order for just a part of the json structure? You will probably need to encode/serialize it manually.

Comment: got it ! we can use encoder.outputFormatting = .init(rawValue:1)

Comment: No I mean using JSONSerialization or constructing your string manually using string interpolation to add the properties at an specific order

Comment: I am getting error response when order of json changes while making payment in authorise.net transaction request.text = "The element 'transactionRequest' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has invalid child element 'amount' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'transactionType' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.";
            }

Comment: Again you need to create a computed property. Add it to your transaction structure

Comment: `var json: String {
        let ctr = createTransactionRequest
        let ma = ctr.merchantAuthentication
        let ctrtr = ctr.transactionRequest
        let od = ctrtr.payment.opaqueData
        return """
            { "createTransactionRequest": { "merchantAuthentication": { "name": "\(ma.name)", "transactionKey": "\(ma.transactionKey)" }, "refId": "\(ctr.refId)", "transactionRequest": { "transactionType": "\(ctrtr.transactionType)", "amount": "\(ctrtr.amount)", "payment": { "opaqueData": { "dataDescriptor": "\(od.dataDescriptor)", "dataValue": "\(od.dataValue)" } } } } }
  """`

Comment: and this `var data: Data {
        return Data(json.utf8)
    }`

Comment: now you can create your transaction object and pass the data property. `print(transaction.json)` and send `transaction.data`

Comment: This is not so difficult it took me 5 minutes to create that custom string

Comment: How can I add to transaction structure ?     struct Transaction: Codable { let createTransactionRequest: CreateTransactionRequest}